# How can I disable GNU C compiler/GCC warnings without touching source code?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

There're tons of redundant explanations about how to disable GCC warnings being treated as errors as developer of the source code. Now, I'd like to know if there's a way to disable them without touching the source code (including build tool configuration files), i.e., let the compilation continue ignoring the warning. In my understand of the GCC documentation at *[Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)*, `CXXFLAGS="-w"` should be sufficient if specified for `./configure` and `make`, e.g., `CXXFLAGS="-w" ./configure && make`.

Remark: I know that it is not a good idea to compile a program against the intentions of the developers and communicating an issue and fixing it together is always the better option if not the only.

Background (please read the whole question, especially the remark above and below, I'm not looking for a fix for the following issue!): I'm trying to compile [QEMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU) Git tag v2.1.0 in a Debian 7.6 chroot on Synology DSM 5.0 with armv7 architecture and getting

```
  CC    migration-rdma.o

migration-rdma.c: In function 'ram_chunk_start':
migration-rdma.c:521:12: error: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Werror=int-to-pointer-cast]
migration-rdma.c: In function '__qemu_rdma_add_block':
migration-rdma.c:553:49: error: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Werror=int-to-pointer-cast]
migration-rdma.c:554:49: error: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Werror=int-to-pointer-cast]
migration-rdma.c: In function '__qemu_rdma_delete_block':
migration-rdma.c:661:45: error: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Werror=int-to-pointer-cast]
migration-rdma.c:696:49: error: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Werror=int-to-pointer-cast]
migration-rdma.c: In function 'qemu_rdma_search_ram_block':
migration-rdma.c:1109:49: error: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Werror=int-to-pointer-cast]
migration-rdma.c: In function 'qemu_rdma_register_and_get_keys':
migration-rdma.c:1172:50: error: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Werror=pointer-to-int-cast]
migration-rdma.c:1173:29: error: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Werror=pointer-to-int-cast]
migration-rdma.c:1173:51: error: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Werror=pointer-to-int-cast]
migration-rdma.c:1174:29: error: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Werror=pointer-to-int-cast]
migration-rdma.c: In function 'qemu_rdma_post_send_control':
migration-rdma.c:1558:36: error: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Werror=pointer-to-int-cast]
migration-rdma.c: In function 'qemu_rdma_post_recv_control':
migration-rdma.c:1614:37: error: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Werror=pointer-to-int-cast]
migration-rdma.c: In function 'qemu_rdma_write_one':
migration-rdma.c:1862:16: error: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Werror=pointer-to-int-cast]
migration-rdma.c:1866:53: error: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Werror=int-to-pointer-cast]
migration-rdma.c:1920:52: error: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Werror=int-to-pointer-cast]
migration-rdma.c:1921:50: error: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Werror=int-to-pointer-cast]
migration-rdma.c:1975:49: error: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Werror=int-to-pointer-cast]
migration-rdma.c:1996:49: error: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Werror=int-to-pointer-cast]
migration-rdma.c:2008:58: error: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Werror=int-to-pointer-cast]
migration-rdma.c: In function 'qemu_rdma_registration_handle':
migration-rdma.c:3021:21: error: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Werror=pointer-to-int-cast]
migration-rdma.c:3086:41: error: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Werror=pointer-to-int-cast]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [migration-rdma.o] Error 1
```

I played around with some options, and now I just want to know whether it's possible or not in order to achieve better inside in the GNU build tools. I'm very certain that the build result will be at least unreliable if not unusable.

BTW: If you found this through a search engine and are having same or similar trouble with QEMU, see *[Build of v2.1.0 fails on armv7l due to undeclared __NR_select](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1363641)*.

Comment: Don't disable GCC warnings, they are so useful (and here, they show an issue in your code). If you insist, change the `CFLAGS` of your `Makefile` (or of your `make` command); and the *errors should be corrected*

Comment: Warnings in external packages is something you unfortunately have to live with, and instead of just silencing them you should pester the package authors to fix it.

Comment: That's what I wrote in the question!!

Comment: Could someone please explain the downvotes. There're so far no comment which are relating to the whole question like I asked it! I explicitly stated that what I want to do "is not a good idea" and I only want to "acchieve better inside in the GNU build tools".

Comment: The program will simply not work. Or it as least very unlikely to. It is putting pointer in integers that are too small for pointers. Either your compiler is not set up correctly (it thinks pointers are 64bit while they are really 32, are you cross compiling?) or you for some reason have a 64-bit ARMv7.  So even if you turn off warnings it will not get you in any way closer to a working program. The most likely error is that you are compiling using the wrong compiler or header files.

Comment: The other alternative is that the integers are 64bit while the pointers are not. IN that case the code will never work on arm at all, unless you can disable it somehow or rewrite it to use 32bit values for the DMA stuff (which might be somewhat complex, partly due to the much smaller address space you have to play around with) you are EOL.

Comment: @perh I agree absolutely which is why I wrote "I'm very certain that the build result will be at least unreliable if not unusable." (citing myself, AGAIN!) in my question!

Comment: Well, there is -Wno-<option> that you can use, but the order of arguments will be rather important. The easiest way is to simply remove the -W<option> from the makefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about the `-w` option, and the easiest way to make sure it propagates everywhere is to put it in the `CC` variable: `CC="gcc -w" ./configure ...`

However, if they turned on *this warning as an error* specifically, then I don't think you should try to disable it. In that case, the code was obviously intended for this warning not to be possible, and it's likely that something is horribly wrong in your toolchain (e.g. integer types are defined wrong, so that a type they expect to be the same size as pointers is not). You should try to track this issue down or you're just going to be wasting your time with a broken build that crashes when you run it. Why not look at some of the source lines the warning messages reference and see what's actually going on?